# How to get target element of click event in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to add a modal to Ember app and got this template:

```
<div class="modal-overlay" {{action "close"}}>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{yield}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I click inside body element, the click event bubbles and triggers `close` action on the overlay. If I try to prevent bubbling by adding an action that doesn't do anything to the body element:

```
<div class="modal-overlay" {{action "close"}}>
  <div class="modal-body" {{action "nop" bubbles=false>
    {{yield}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't click any links in the body anymore...

What's the best way to solve it? If I could access click event in the `close` action, I could check if the element clicked was actually the overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most modals I've seen have solved this by structuring things differently. Checkout [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) for example. It would look kinda like this for you.

```
<div class="modal-overlay" {{action "close"}}></div>
<div class="modal-wrap">
    <div class="modal-body>
        {{yield}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, it's looks like the standard way for modals. :)

Comment: I was hoping somebody will figure out how to access native click event in Ember actions, as it would be useful in some other places as well, but this suggestion does solve this problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found to access the target element was using jquery

```
didInsertElement(){
        this.$()
            .on('click', '.gn-icon-menu', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
```

event holds the target element. So notice im not using ember actions here.